# ssh with publickey not working althought the rights on the files in .ssh are fine

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

Cannot connect to an OpenSSHD server.

Here is the situation :

```bash
client $ ls -al .ssh/
total 16
drwx------  2 administrateur administrateur 4096 Nov 30 15:32 ./
drwxr-x--- 14 administrateur administrateur 4096 Nov 30 15:32 ../
-rw-------  1 administrateur administrateur 2675 Nov 30 15:04 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 administrateur administrateur 1768 Nov 30 15:01 known_hosts
server $ ls -al .ssh/
total 12
drwx------ 2 git git 4096 nov.  30 15:34 .
drwxr-x--- 9 git git 4096 nov.  30 15:34 ..
-rw------- 1 git git  886 nov.  30 15:12 authorized_keys
```

Here is what happens :

```bash
client $ ssh-copy-id git@server
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
git@server_s password:

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'git@server'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.

client $ ssh-add -l
3072 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX administrateur@CLIENT (RSA)
client $ ssh git@server
git@server_s password:
```

So I tried running the server in debug mode on port 2222 and then do a `ssh -p 2222 git@server` :

```bash
server $ sudo $(which sshd) -d -p 2222
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #2 type 3 ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #3 type 4 ED25519
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='2222'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 2222.

### Connecting from client to server on port 2222 ###

debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 172.16.5.83 port 47084 on 172.16.5.140 port 2222
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 104/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user git service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "git"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "par-postgres01.orion.lan"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"


### Now appears the ssh prompt so I type the password instead ###


debug1: userauth-request for user git service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: password authentication accepted for git
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted password for git from 172.16.5.83 port 47086 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: git has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
User child is on pid 11239
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 105/115
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/5
debug1: Ignoring unsupported tty mode opcode 42 (0x2a)
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
Starting session: shell on pts/5 for git from 172.16.5.83 port 47086
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
debug1: session_by_tty: session 0 tty /dev/pts/5
debug1: Unable to open session: The name org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit was not provided by any .service files
```

And are the variables displayed on the client side :

```bash
Last login: Wed Nov 30 15:31:22 2022 from client
Environment:
  LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
  USER=git
  LOGNAME=git
  HOME=/git/
  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
  MAIL=/var/mail/git
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  SSH_CLIENT=172.16.5.83 47086 2222
  SSH_CONNECTION=172.16.5.83 47086 172.16.5.140 2222
  SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/5
  TERM=xterm
  XDG_SESSION_ID=114077
git@server:~$ déconnexion
Connection to server closed.
```

And here is the SSHD configuration on the server :

```bash
server $ sudo egrep -v '^(#|$)' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
```

Here is the client log :

```bash
$ ssh -vv -p2222 git@server
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "server" port 2222
debug1: Connecting to server [172.16.5.140] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.13 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to server:2222 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/administrateur/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:AkYT7N1FHn9cd1nkTNt1/S5pcXKNkizpM6pifhSV+uY
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/administrateur/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/administrateur/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'server' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/administrateur/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug1: check_host_key: hostkey not known or explicitly trusted: disabling UpdateHostkeys
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XOoqCfyDPSinHDaNokW0oo6sauWik03yD6Jp8CVGQKU agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/administrateur/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@server's password:
```

Comment: What about the logging on the client side?  `ssh -vv -p2222 git@...`

Comment: @user4556274 Just added the logging you asked.

Comment: Required information in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646572/ssh-rsa-public-key-authentication-explanation-needed , although there should be better candidates for duplicate, seen multiple related questions lately.  Key info in client logging is "send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm"

Comment: (Note: the string you tried to obfuscate survived in another line.)

Answer (score 1):

```
send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

To me this seems like the relevant line. The key that you are trying to use uses an algorithm that your server doesn't accept.

Do you use an .ssh config file on the client? I find those really useful.

You can specify alot of information about your host, like this:

```
Host quodlibet
HostName 172.28.104.99
User root
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/name-of-private-key-ecdsa
```

It looks like it is trying every key you have, so it might be helpful to specify the key you want to use.

Can you verify that your key has been added to the authorized_keys file? I usually manually copy my public key to the end of that file on the server.

Comment: I don't understand this `send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm` message. Isn't `SHA256` used on both sides ?